# Google getting two results to the same question

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, google

Searching for [this](http://www.google.com/#q=list+to+enumerable) in Google: `list to enumerable`, getting two results to the same question, on SO.

1. [When to use each of T[], List<T>, IEnumerable<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410590/when-to-use-each-of-t-listt-ienumerablet)
2. [When to use each of T[], List<T>, IEnumerable<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410590/when-to-use-each-of-t-listst-ienumerablet)

I guess that this is because the different in the question title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google needs to resolve this, not us. The ID is unique.

Comment: Of course. Since you have the `canonical` tag.

Comment: +1 for the canonical tag. So this is no problem.

Answer (score 2):

Initially, the title of this question was “When to use each of T[], **Lists**<T>, IEnumerable<T>?”. 5 minutes later, the **Lists**<T> was fixed to **List**<T>. This explains the `listst` → `listt` in the URL.

I don't think it's a [`[bug]`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug) on SO's side. It's Google that doesn't know the two links point to the same page. But both of them will reach the same page, so it shouldn't be a big problem.

Comment: Um, I never said anything like that. I said 'the crawler is just self-tuning to make search results as "fresh" as possible without trying to hit every web site in the world every 20 seconds' which isn't the same thing at all.